# Prevent keyboard from shifting page up in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cordova, keyboard

Is there an Xcode project preference setting (.plist?) that prevents the keyboard from shifting the whole page up?

Thank you.

Comment: Honestly, you didn't even provide a tenth of enough information for anyone to answer. Clarify?

Comment: Really? Since in a project .plist file you can hide your status bar or deactivate the gloss effect on your app icon, I was simply asking if you can somehow influence the default behaviour of a page shifting upwards when the keyboard is displayed.

Comment: What does this have to do with Xcode? What "page" is getting shifted up?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I'm not sure sorry, might want to clarify that in your question. :)